# Using .html() to dynamically generate content but js styling is not applied after using .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm building a website to use with Cordova on mobile. I found this great javascript framework called nativedroid2. This framework generates html classes, effects and the like which are applied to html code.

Now what I am trying to do is dynamically generating html code in jQuery by using AJAX calls to a server (I want javascript to make the HTML to remove the load of the server). However when I try to use `html()` on some divs to load some HTML, the nativedroid javascript function does not apply to the HTML, so no styling is done and everything looks like I am not even using nativedroid2. I am not using AJAX calls yet because I was testing if the `html()` works with nativedroid.

```
var html1;
var html2;

function loadpage(id, data) {
  generateContent(id, data);

  $('[data-role="header"]').html(html1);
  $('[role="main"]').html(html2);
}

function generateContent(id, data) {
  html1 = "bunch of html for the header"
  html2 = "bunch of html for the body"
```

Does anyone know a better alternative to `html()` or a fix to make this work?

Comment: you are missing "]" in $('[role="main"')

Comment: Thank you, edited in the question (doesn't change anything tho)

Comment: You say that nativedroid2 adds classes to your HTML. When does it do that? And can you call the function that generates the classes manually for the newly added HTML? The problem probably lies in the fact that nativedroid2 applies the classes to the existing HTML but not to your dynamically added HTML. No classes means no styling.

Comment: @vi5ion I tried to use a boolean variable to call the function that calls the nativedroid code so that it only generates the classes when the new html is added but that did not work. And you're right only the parts in the normal html file are styled but I made sure the nativedroid functions are called later by using print statements.

Comment: @WouterLoeve I've tried to find anything in the nativedroid2 documentation, but I haven't found anything on handling dynamic content. I've also scrolled through some of their JS code, but as far as I can tell there's no functionality in there that supports it either. Maybe they do support it and I just didn't see it, but so far I'm afraid that it's simply not supported :(

Comment: @vi5ion Thank you for your time, do you know of a way to program the dynamic aspect in myself?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I read online that I had to escape the quotation marks. I used an online tool for that. However the online tool made `"` into `""`, which is read as an empty string. Removing that fixed it.

Thank you for your time if you answered

Answer (score -2):

**Alternative for html()**

You can use JavaScript function **createElement()**

```
var P_tag=$("#your_div_id").createElement('p');
```

This will create an element P-tag, after that, you can set text to it

```
P_tag.text("Text");
```

Comment: get return from the function @Wouter

Comment: I am using html1 and html2 as global variables, maybe not the best practice but the problem isn't adding the html but styling the created html using the nativedroid framework.

Also tried to use createElement but it doesn't recognize it as a function.